# My angular 7 (click)s are not triggering when the page loads, but they work if I destroy and re initialize the component

Tags: html, angular, typescript

There is quite a bit of code involved but here's the gist(I suspect a life-cycle error but not sure): **EDIT: please scroll to the end to see the problem**

I have a Component hierarchy as such:
Dashboard -> Tile -> accordion -> Expandable panels -> Card Components

The dashboard has many tiles(implements onInit), the tile (implements onInit) in question contains an accordion(Implements AfterContentInit), which contains panels that expand and emit click events to the accordion.

To populate the cards and panels i have an object from an api that feeds a behaviorSubject stream. there is some logic done to build the panels dynamically, then populate the card components inside the correct expansion body. If i have a static object that is build onInit and then used in the *ngFor directive it works fine, but now that its structured this way

```
<dcs-panel [title]="bucket.title" *ngFor="let bucket of productCategories$ | async">
    <dcs-prod-card *ngFor="let card of bucket.cards" [card]="card"></dcs-prod-card>
</dcs-panel>
```

It all loads fine and is present in the inspector, but the (clicks) to expand the panels just dont do anything. No errors or indication as to why, they just do nothing. But i have this in an ngIf directive because the tile has two views:

```
<div class="tile-content">
    <!--All Products Template-->
    <div *ngIf="_btnView; else myCardDisplay ">
      <dcs-accordion>
        <dcs-panel [title]="bucket.title" *ngFor="let bucket of productCategories$ | async">
          <dcs-prod-card *ngFor="let card of bucket.cards" [card]="card"></dcs-prod-card>
        </dcs-panel>
      </dcs-accordion>
    </div>

    <!--My Product Display Template-->
    <ng-template #myCardDisplay>
      <div *ngFor="let card of _myProductCards" class="container-crd-myProducts">
        <dcs-my-card [card]="card"></dcs-my-card>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  </div>
```

Once the first template is destroyed and reinitialized IT WORKS AGAIN. But if you reload the page its back to square one.

I know this is tough to go on but im really not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions would be very welcome!

Edit: Here is more of the applicable code,

the accordion parent component

```
<div class="accordion-display">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

```
export class DcsAccordionComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(DcsPanelComponent) panels: QueryList<DcsPanelComponent>;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // Loop through all panels
    this.panels.toArray().forEach((t) => {
      // subscribe panel toggle event
      t.toggle.subscribe(() => {
        // Open the panel
        this.openPanel(t);
      });
    });
  }

 ngOnDestroy() {
    this.panels.toArray().forEach((t) => {
      t.toggle.unsubscribe();
    });
```

the panel component

```
<div class="panel panel-info" >
  <div class="panel-heading" (click)="toggle.emit()" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': opened ? '#150f90' : 'white' , 'color': opened ? 'white' : 'black'}" >
    <div class="title">{{title}}</div>
    <div [ngClass]="{'arrow-closed': !opened, 'arrow-opened': opened}"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body" [ngClass]="{'opened':  opened}" [ngStyle]="{'visibility' : opened ? '' : 'hidden'}" >
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
export class DcsPanelComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @Input() opened = false;
  @Input() title: string;
  @Input() products: Card[];
  @Output() toggle: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {}

  panelClick(event: any) {
    console.log('click', event);
  }
}
```

This is the code that broke the component

```
 setProductCategories() {
    if (this._allProductCards.length == 0) {
      return;
    }
    this.productCategories = [
      {
        title: 'Arance',
        products: [''],
        cards: [],
      },
      {
        title: 'Busiicy',
        products: ['BOP'],
        cards: [],
      },
      {
        title: 'Bds',
        products: ['Asset Managers'],
        cards: [],
      },
      {
        title: 'Cr',
        products: ['CybERM', 'DigERM'],
        cards: [],
      },
      {
        title: 'Ulla',
        products: ['Ulla'],
        cards: [],
      },
    ];

    for (let bucket of this.productCategories) {
      for (let card of this._allProductCards) {
        if (bucket.products.includes(card.title)) {
          bucket.cards.push(card);
        }
      }

    }
    this.productCategories$.next(this.productCategories);
  }
```

the change is that this occurs after the card components are built where it sorts them and puts them into categorical buckets so i know which expansion panel to put them in. before i had the object instantiated on ngInit and the cards were sorted as they were built.

The reason I built it this way is that now when the panel is created it receives the list of cards it owns and exists with all the components that belongs to it per instance of panel. Before all the cards belonged to the Parent,Parent,Parent component and it ran a loop per panel to see which ones to populate into the expansion panel. I felt the new way exemplified coding principals better.

After some Debugging I have found that the click event works on the panels but the event emitter isnt emitting events! So the panels arent communicating with the accordion parent on initial page load... Why is this?

Sorry for all the edits guys, Ok so i console.log'd the panels, and they have no observers OnInit, but when i destroy and instantiate after the ng-content has been populated the observer array=1, so I need the observer to subscribe on page load instead of whatever is happening now.

Is this a problem of accordion.wait for panels.wait for cards?

Alright good concrete example of what works vs what doesnt!

**WORKS**
In this example the panels are init before the accordion.

```
<dcs-panel [title]="'bucket'" *ngFor="let n of [0,1,2,3,4]">
          <dcs-prod-card *ngFor="let card of _allProductCards" [card]="card"></dcs-prod-card>
</dcs-panel>
```

**Does Not Work**
In this example the panels are init after the accordion component.

```
<dcs-panel [title]="bucket.title" *ngFor="let bucket of productCategories">
    <dcs-prod-card *ngFor="let card of bucket.cards" [card]="card"></dcs-prod-card>
</dcs-panel>
```

Why doesnt the accordion component wait for the panels in the second example?

Comment: Can you please post your .ts code?

Comment: Are you using onPush change detection strategy?

Comment: @penleychan I was not aware of this, i enabled it, same effect

Comment: Can you add the markup that has the click handler on it? `(click)`

Comment: @inorganik good call, thanks for the comment code is posted with brief explanation

Comment: When is setProductCategories called? I feel like it's your ngAfterContentInit hook that's the problem as it is only called once see the [docs](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentInit).

Comment: @Mickers i suspect the same issue, but the setProductCategories() is called from another function that pieces two api returns together into an array of cards, once all the cards are built this function is called. The other thing that might be a problem is that buildAllCards is called from two streams, when either stream receives a change so this function is called multiple times.

Comment: My suggestion is to move this line "this.panels.toArray" inside your ngAfterContentInit to a separate private method. Then add an ngOnit hook and subscribe to the productCategories$ subject and call that new method anytime it changes. I believe might help you figure out why your panels are getting out of sync

Comment: @Mickers thank you so much for your suggestion! I will play with the Init functions more, but if i subscribe to that subject from the accordion component, the accordion component is no longer modular. It only works in this instance and i would have to create a whole new accordion component for any other situation.